# Wien Bridge Oscillator using OpAmp(LM386) works in simulation, but doesn't work in Breadboard?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, oscillator, wien-bridge, 741-opamp

[image]

This is a simulation of the circuit in multisim. It is a Wien bridge oscillator circuit, tuned at 1844Hz. I am mostly interested in generating sound of that frequency. It seems to work here in simulation but when I connect a speaker to the output, I dont get anything. Connected a LED as well, im getting nothing.

I am not sure where the problem is. Is the supply voltage of  +/- 6V a reason? I am using a 12V power supply, split in half through virtual ground technique. 
Any idea on where the problem might be? How can I fix it to make some 1844hz sound with a speaker?

Comment: why are you simulating a (hopelessly bad and outdated, don't use it) 741 but then use a completely different device, the LM386, on breadboard? That's like complaining that when you were simulating it on a PC, you could go 300 km/h in your racing car, but now, you can't even get off the spot using your wooden raft on the street...

Comment: With an output waveform like that, it's a lousy Wien bridge even if you use the correct parts.Gain should be 3 + a tiny fraction, not 4.5  (or use thermistor or lightbulb to stabilise gain at precisely 3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LM386 is not an op-amp, it is a speaker amplifier chip. So it does not work in a circuit that is built around an op-amp.

Comment: Alright, giving that a try. 
Thanks for the help!